# 3D Transformation Ignoring Clip Path

Tags: css, css-transforms

I have a parent `div#clipper` with a `clip-path`, which clips a child `div#object`. When I apply a 3D transformation to `#object`, no matter the values, the element stops obeying the clip and shows as if no clip was applied.

[Here's a demonstration.](https://jsfiddle.net/pzsLm42z/)

HTML:

```
<div id="clipper">
  <div id="object"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#clipper, #object {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#clipper {
  clip-path: inset(30px);
}

#object {
  transform: translate3d(1px, 1px, 1px);
  background-color: #3FA;
}
```

This appears to happen in both Chrome and Firefox. Is there a documented reason why? How can I prevent it?

Comment: Using clip-path can cause 'flattening' in a css3 3d object, good article at [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/things-watch-working-css-3d) about it

Comment: seems to be working in chrome at least https://jsfiddle.net/pzsLm42z/3/ or was it about overflow http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aBQBZX ?

Comment: @GCyrillus The child element is not being clipped for me in your fiddle, in chrome 55. Is it necessary to specify hidden overflow? If so, why would 2D translations automatically clip, but not 3D translations? https://jsfiddle.net/0wwpxm53/

Comment: chrome 58 has solved this issue.

Comment: @sangelee I can't find any relevant announcement or issue fix from the Chromium team. Source?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the CSS specs:

> 13.5 SVG and 3D transform functions
>
> This specification explicitly requires three-dimensional transform
>   functions to apply to the container elements: , , , all
>   graphics elements, all graphics referencing elements and the SVG
>    element.
>
> Three-dimensional transform functions and the properties perspective,
>   perspective-origin, transform-style and backface-visibility can not be
>   used for the elements: **clipPath**, linearGradient, radialGradient
>   and pattern. If a transform list includes a **three-dimensional
>   transform** function, the complete transform list must be **ignored**. The
>   values of every previously named property must be ignored.
>   Transformable elements that are contained by one of these elements can
>   have three-dimensional transform functions. The , ,
>    elements require the user agent to create a flattened
>   representation of the descendant elements before they can be applied,
>   and therefore override the behavior of transform-style: preserve-3d.
>
> If the vector-effect property is set to non-scaling-stroke and an
>   object is within a 3D rendering context the property has no affect on
>   stroking the object.

[documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#svg-three-dimensional-functions)

It's talking about SVG, but I guess that the same rule extends to non-SVG elements